# How to transpose rows and colums from a SQL query

Tags: sql, dynamic, transpose

How to transpose rows and colums from a SQL query as below. Using SQL Server 2012 to write a query that will work even as data is added to the database table

[image]

Comment: Show us what is your desire output and what gave you try and what is your rdbms.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM t_TableName GROUP BY Month
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ff598/55)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable
    ( 
       [mon] varchar(3), [to] float, [aapl] float,
       [msft] float, [ko] float
    )
;

INSERT INTO yourtable
([mon],[to],[aapl],[msft],[ko])
VALUES
    ('jan', 12.25,112.25,56.52,45 ),
    ('feb', 12.52,125.25,56.87,46),
    ('mar', 12.65,126,56.94,47),
    ('apr', 12.95,127,56.99,45),
    ('may', 12.85,129,57.25,44)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from yourtable
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ff598/55/0)**:

```
| mon |    to |   aapl |  msft | ko |
|-----|-------|--------|-------|----|
| jan | 12.25 | 112.25 | 56.52 | 45 |
| feb | 12.52 | 125.25 | 56.87 | 46 |
| mar | 12.65 |    126 | 56.94 | 47 |
| apr | 12.95 |    127 | 56.99 | 45 |
| may | 12.85 |    129 | 57.25 | 44 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select *
from
(
  select *
  from yourtable
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for month in ([to],[aapl],[msft],[ko])
  ) unpiv
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for mon in (jan, feb, mar, apr, may)
) piv
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ff598/55/1)**:

```
| month |    jan |    feb |   mar |   apr |   may |
|-------|--------|--------|-------|-------|-------|
|  aapl | 112.25 | 125.25 |   126 |   127 |   129 |
|    ko |     45 |     46 |    47 |    45 |    44 |
|  msft |  56.52 |  56.87 | 56.94 | 56.99 | 57.25 |
|    to |  12.25 |  12.52 | 12.65 | 12.95 | 12.85 |
```